# API Gateway and Lambda function from command line

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to deploy an API on AWS using a bash script which uses `aws-cli`, and by calling this API I want to trigger a Lambda function which does some computation and store some data on DynamoDB. Actually I am able do deploy everything through my script, but when I call my API I get this error

- header

```json
{"x-amzn-ErrorType":"InternalServerErrorException"}
```

- body

```json
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

- log

```
Execution log for request a5be6fcf-0025-4929-bc95-8cc816cc5b0b
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Starting execution for request: a5be6fcf-0025-4929-bc95-8cc816cc5b0b
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Method request path: {}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Method request query string: {}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Method request headers: {}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Method request body before transformations: {
    "device": {
        "uuid": "4",
        "lastPosition": "4",
        "lastSeen": "4",
        "raspberryId": "4",
        "roomNumber": "34"
    }
}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***:function:prova/invocations
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=a5be6fcf-0025-4929-bc95-8cc816cc5b0b, Authorization=************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************5522b6, X-Amz-Date=20201126T185559Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=d87wgvuxb3, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:***:d87wgvuxb3/test-invoke-stage/POST/{proxy+}, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_d87wgvuxb3, X-Amz-Security-Token=*** [TRUNCATED]
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"body": {"device":{"uuid":"4","lastPosition":"4","lastSeen":"4","raspberryId":"4","roomNumber":"34"}}}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***:function:prova/invocations
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 219 ms
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Thu, 26 Nov 2020 18:55:59 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=172, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=1440b32a-d93e-4933-98c2-5d54ef91a7ab, X-Amz-Function-Error=Unhandled, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5fbffa3f-ebf6507c614e2e39e7d2eae2;sampled=0}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "'device'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    device = event['device']\n"]}
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 200
Thu Nov 26 18:55:59 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 500
```

The thing is that the Lambda function runs correctly because I can find the data in my DynamoDB table, but I receive an error as a response. If I deploy an API that triggers the same function through the AWS console itself everything works properly.

This is how I deploy my API

```sh
#!/bin/sh
api_id=$(aws apigateway create-rest-api --name 'prova' --query 'id' --output text)
resource_id=$(aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id $api_id --query 'items' --output text)
resource_id=${resource_id::-2}
result_id=$(aws apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id $api_id --parent-id $resource_id --path-part prova --query 'id' --output text)

aws apigateway put-method \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --authorization-type "NONE"

aws apigateway put-method-response \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \ 
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --status-code 200 

aws apigateway put-integration \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --type AWS \
    --integration-http-method POST \
    --uri arn:aws:apigateway:$AWS_REGION:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:$AWS_REGION:$ACCOUNT_ID:function:prova/invocations \
    --request-templates '{"application/json":"{\"body\": $input.json(\"$\")}"}'

aws apigateway put-integration-response \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --rest-api-id $api_id \
    --resource-id $result_id \
    --http-method POST \
    --status-code 200 \
    --selection-pattern ""

aws lambda add-permission \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --function-name prova \
    --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
    --statement-id AllowGatewayToInvokeFunction \
    --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com

aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id $api_id --stage-name prova
```

And last question, how I can know the `Invoke URL` of the API created through CLI without accessing to the AWS Console?

Comment: what is the response returned by the lamba?

Comment: It's a python function which returns `return { 'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps('Device added!') }`. But as I said in the question, if I deploy an API for the same Lambda function it works without problems.

Comment: According to the logs the body is `{"errorMessage": "'device'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    device = event['device']\n"]}`  You didn't share the lambda  src, so how do you handle the exceptions?

Comment: I don't think it's an exception handling matter, because as said before, if I deploy an API from the console itself for the same lambda function it works. So, it must be related to the way the API is deployed through CLI. There must be something wrong with that code.

Comment: You did not provide any code or code difference with difference deployment or difference in the gw/integration config, so the only visible issue is the exception in the log. But I'd advice to check if there is any difference in the integration or the integration response

Comment: It could be that when you deployed using the console, the config that you chose is different from the config you have specified in your CLI command. I would suggest deploying it again via AWS Console and you post screenshots of those options that you chose when deploying via AWS Console. I would want to look at the integration type.

Comment: I solved by adding `--response-templates '{"application/json": ""}'` in `put-integration-response`. Now it works, but the stage is at `url/prova/prova`, instead I want it at `url/prova`.